# Glassfish 5 : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException with JSF Hello World

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, glassfish, java-ee-8

**Hello, I'm trying to run a Hello World JSF with Glassfish 5 but I get the error as following:**

```
C:\glassfish5\glassfish\bin\asadmin.bat start-domain domain1
"C:\Program Files\Zulu\zulu-11\bin\java.exe" -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -classpath C:\Users\Nuklearka\AppData\Local\Temp\classpath2016962722.jar com.intellij.javaee.oss.process.JavaeeProcess 52254 com.intellij.javaee.oss.glassfish.agent.Glassfish31Agent
Detected server admin port: 4848
[2022-01-29 03:14:30,037] Artifact JSF:war exploded: Waiting for server connection to start artifact deployment...
Detected server http port: 8080
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.enterprise.module.common_impl.AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.initializeServiceLocator(AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.java:152)
    at com.sun.enterprise.module.common_impl.AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.newServiceLocator(AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.java:144)
    at com.sun.enterprise.module.common_impl.AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.createServiceLocator(AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.java:218)
    at com.sun.enterprise.module.common_impl.AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.createServiceLocator(AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.java:224)
    at com.sun.enterprise.module.single.StaticModulesRegistry.createServiceLocator(StaticModulesRegistry.java:88)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.CLIContainer.getServiceLocator(CLIContainer.java:217)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.CLIContainer.getLocalCommand(CLIContainer.java:255)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.CLICommand.getCommand(CLICommand.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.AdminMain.executeCommand(AdminMain.java:371)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.AdminMain.doMain(AdminMain.java:306)
    at org.glassfish.admin.cli.AsadminMain.main(AsadminMain.java:57)
```

**I'm using:
Glassfish 5.0.0 and JDK 11**

Answer (score 0):

GlassFish 5 doesn't run on JDK 11. The current version, 6.2.4 at the time of writing does. You can download that from e.g. here:

https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/glassfish/releases/tag/6.2.4